# Why twitter plugin (widget) doesn't show up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

If you look at my site www.tripleflowmusic.com, once you load the page, other HTML document with twitter plugin is loaded (Updates.html) in to container with help of of following code (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subpageframe").load('Pages/Updates.html', function(){
        $("#subpageframe").fadeIn(200);
```

But when I click News button, which does the following thing (It basically reloads Updates.html in the container):

```
$("#UpdatesButton").click(function() {
    $("#subpageframe").fadeOut(200, function() {
        $("#subpageframe").load('Pages/Updates.html', function(){
            $("#subpageframe").fadeIn(200);
```

The twitter plugin won't show

The question is, why is this happening?

P.S. To get access to sub pages, simply remove "#" from the URL in the address bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iframe and format isn't there like it is on the homepage. This code is in the homepage but not in http://www.tripleflowmusic.com/#Pages/Updates.html:

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" allowfullscreen="" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline-block; position: static; visibility: visible; width: 520px;" title="Twitter Timeline" height="600"></iframe>
```

You have some "a class" and "style" in the news page instead of the proper

```
<center data-twttr-id="twttr-sandbox-0">
```

format.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry, the code I used was generated on Twitter website itself.
http://www.tripleflowmusic.com/Pages/Updates.html
Plus I didn't use iframes on my website

Answer (score 0):

Shows fine on both Safari and Chrome on OS X for me, can you be more specific with what browser you're using and OS?

While we are at it you might want to clean up some of the errors that are being thrown:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not     Found)
http://www.tripleflowmusic.com/FunctionElements/MusicPlayer/Covers/missing.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://www.tripleflowmusic.com/MediaElements/MusicPlayer/Songs/nylmbyb.mp3 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I used Chrome and Firefox, did you click News button? Button basically reloads "Updates.html" page in the container which is called "subpageframe". First time when you visit the site jQuery loads "Updates.html" into "subpageframe" when document is ready and it shows up. The problem is, after I click news, twitter plug-in won't appear :(

Yes, in this case it's fine, it's just tries to load a dummy tack and it's cover to the player upon page load, which i removed from the server for now :)

Comment: And yes, it always does appear here when I reaload it ---> http://www.tripleflowmusic.com/Pages/Updates.html , it only doesn't when I reload it within a "subpageframe" container on my website